# Exception when doing min, max or sum from OData to EFcore

Tags: c#, linq, odata, entity-framework-core

I have a simple project and when I want to get sum from OData

`http://localhost:31187/api/Northwind/AppEntityType?$apply=aggregate(OptimisticLockField%20with%20max%20as%20maxOLF)`

occures an exception:

> "message": "Could not parse expression '$it.AsQueryable()': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable' is currently not supported.",
>   "type": "System.NotSupportedException"

Remotion.Linq throws that exception.

Is this function really not supported in OData with EFCore or that's my mistake?

UPD. to avoid this exception it's necessary to create your own class, that represents ur AsQueryableNode;

```
public class AsQueryableNode : MethodCallExpressionNodeBase
  {
    public static readonly MethodInfo[] SupportedMethods = new[]
                                                       {
                                                           GetSupportedMethod (() => Queryable.AsQueryable<object> (null)),
                                                       };

public AsQueryableNode (MethodCallExpressionParseInfo parseInfo)
    : base(parseInfo)
{
}

public override Expression Resolve (ParameterExpression inputParameter, Expression expressionToBeResolved, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
{
  // pass on expression to previous node
  return Source.Resolve (inputParameter, expressionToBeResolved, clauseGenerationContext);
}

protected override QueryModel ApplyNodeSpecificSemantics (QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
{
  // don't change query model
  return queryModel;
}
```

}

Then u need to register AsQueryable method in MethodInfoBasedNodeTypeRegistry class and problem solved.

Comment: I've run into this as well when using OData 7.0 (nightlies) and ASP.NET Core.  I've logged the issue at https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1154, but it sounds like you had a good workaround in place.  Do you have any examples or more details on how to make this work (I'm having trouble understanding where to register `AsQueryable`).  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some details regarding "registering AsQueryable method" for your workaround? I'm not sure what you mean there